# Does Android have any similar function to setVisibility()?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

[image]

I wanted to change the button4 visibility in the activity but couldn't found setVisibility() function, instead of which there was a visibility function.

what should I use now to change the visibility of the button4?

Comment: Just use `button4.visibility = View.VISIBLE` (or whichever visibility you wanted to set).

Comment: `Does Android Studio. have any similar function` nothing to do with android studio, that's just the IDE you're using

Comment: You're coding in Kotlin. I suggest reading about [Kotlin properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html). It might also help to read about [calling Java from Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Kotlin. You can try

> button4.visibility = View.VISIBLE

OR

> button4.visibility = View.GONE